# GAE GCM Size of message

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, character-encoding

In the GCM documentation (http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html) it states that there's a 4kb payload limit per message. I am struggling to figure out how long my messages are. They're currently simply defined in a String and I use the packages

com.google.android.gcm.server.Message
com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender

to send the messages. The messages sent and received are fine. I'm just wondering if there was a way to see how many bytes each message is at the moment to see how much more I can add. I tried printing out the default encoding using Charset.defaultCharset() but I'm not sure if that's the actual encoding. It returned US-Ascii.

Currently the sending of messages goes something like:

```
Message message;
message = new Message.Builder()
.addData("MESSAGE_TYPE", "version1")
.addData("PERSONNAME", "john")
.addData("PHONENUMBER", "5551234567")
.build();

Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);

try{
MulticastResult result = sender.send(message, registrationIds, 5);
}
```

Is there a way to determine how many bytes the message actually is? Thanks.